# How to use collect() in drools in this scenario

Tags: java, drools, rule

I am trying to do something like below to collect a ecrtain type of objects fullfilling certain conditions.

```
rule "collect_other"
$lineItem2 : A( $iVal : iValue, $qd2 : quantity) 
B($bVal : bId)
$rowLowerOther : C(iValue == $iVal, bId == $bVal,
                   $lsequence : sequence, $jValue : jAvlDate)
$rowHigherOther : List() 
    from collect(C(iValue == $iVal, bId == $bVal,
                   sequence == $lsequence-1, jAvlDate != $jValue))

then
    //do something
end
```

Right Now I am getting one object only even though I am having numbers of object fullfilliong the condition.

Note: I want to collect all items fullfilling conditions by taking the value from first object instance of "C"

Please help me.

Comment: You'll have to show the values of the C objects you are inserting into Working Memory, at least the values of the fields as used in this rule.

Comment: ivalueis integer type, bId is string type, sequence is of integer type and jAvlDate is of String type. What do you mean by showing data.

Comment: I didn't use "showing data". One needs to know the values of the objects of class C inserted into Working Memory to understand what might happen.

Comment: C(101, "BU1","1","2014-11-23");
C(101, "BU1","2","2014-11-24");
C(101, "BU1","3","2014-11-25");
C(101, "BU1","4","2014-11-26"); etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of class C are:

```
C(101, "BU1", 1,"2014-11-23");
C(101, "BU1", 2,"2014-11-24");
C(101, "BU1", 3,"2014-11-25");
C(101, "BU1", 4,"2014-11-26")
```

Let's assume that we have

```
A(101,...)
B("BU1")
```

Then the pattern

```
C(iValue == $iVal, bId == $bVal,$lsequence : sequence,...)
```

matches any of these C objects, binding $lsequence to 1, 2, 3 and so on. For the first binding, the rule doesn't fire, because no C fact matches sequence == 1-1

For each of the values 2, 3, 4 and so on, the rule will match and collect exactly on C fact into the list, i.e., the one with seuqnce == 1, 2, 3,... respectively.

**Perhaps** this does what you want - but I'm only guessing.

```
rule "collect_other"
when
  $lineItem2: A( $iVal: iValue, $qd2 : quantity ) 
              B( $bVal : bId )
  $rowLowerOther: C(iValue == $iVal, bId == $bVal,
                    $lsequence : sequence, $jValue: jAvlDate)
  not C( iValue == $iVal, bId == $bVal, sequence < $lsequence )
  $rowHigherOther : List() 
     from collect(C(iValue == $iVal, bId == $bVal, jAvlDate != $jValue))
then
  //...
end
```

Comment: Hi Laune, thanks for your answer.As I mentioned; I am getting one by one; however I need all the matched one in one single list. How Can i achieve this.

Comment: The problem is that you know what "matched ones" means but I don't as I see only the rule which doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: In a very simple way, I want to collect all the C object types matching all conditions above. I need to pass in a java method in THEN part of rule.